# How can I share files at the Visual Studio solution level that are in different Git repos in a micro services architecture

Tags: git, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, microservices

We have a Micro-services architecture and each service is located in its own Git repo. All services are .Net Core services, and we are using Visual Studio 2017 (soon we'll start using 2019).
We want to share common files that need to be placed at the **solution level** like:

- .editorconfig

  - To distribute common Visual Studio settings
- *.ruleset

  - Analyzer ruleset settings
- .dotsettings

  - ReSharper settings
- roslynator.config

  - Roslynator analyzer settings
- stylecop.json

  - Stylecop analyzer settings

Some of these files require more settings **at the project level**, for those we are using NuGet and *props* files to update the project.
But other files we just want a way to distribute them across repos at the solution level. With the ability to update them easily so if we want to update any rule at the company level, we can easily re-distribute the change across all micro-services.

Unfortunately, NuGet ability to consume/create solution-level packages was deprecated.

We also looked at Git sub-modules, but they only work in a *sub-folder* and we actually want these files at the solution level.

How can we distribute these files in a way that they get copied to the right place (solution level)?

Answer (score 0):

The submodule option is interesting, except you would need to include in it an addition script file which would then *copy*/update those file at the solution level.
Or put symlinks (which [do exist with Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)) at the solution level back to those submodule files.

Plus, you would need to update the `README` of those repository to mention that particular setup/update step, which would require for the user to run that submodule script in order to get a fully operational development environment.